# dlopen failed(return NULL) when add SDL2 to android project

Tags: android, cmake, sdl

I'm adding **SDL2.0.9** to my Android project with **cmake3.6(NDK19)** on Android Studio3.4 , and I got this error :

```
" E/SDL: nativeRunMain(): Couldn't load library /data/app/org.libsdl.app-eOed871MljqNS6cZDl_DBg==/lib/arm64/libmain.so"
```

After debug, I found this line (**library_handle is NULL**)  in SDL2/src/core/androd/SDL_android.c：

```
library_handle = dlopen(library_file, RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (library_handle) {
...
} else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SDL", "nativeRunMain(): Couldn't load library %s", library_file);
}
```

Below is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

file(GLOB my_source ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c)

add_library(main
        SHARED
        main.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2/include)

find_library(log-lib
        log)

target_link_libraries(
        main
        SDL2
        GLESv1_CM
        GLESv2
        -landroid
        ${log-lib})
```

and my **main.cpp**:

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "gmyffplay"
#define LOGV(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

#include "SDL.h"

extern "C" {

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *video_path = argv[1];
    LOGI("video_path  : %s", video_path);

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Event event;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        LOGE("Could not initialize SDL - %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 0, 0,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
    SDL_SetColorKey(bmp, SDL_TRUE, 0xffffff);
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bmp);
    SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT);
    while (1) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                break;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 133, 119, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
}
```

I'm sure the library_file exists,  libmain.so in the apk  and libSDL2 is loaded before libmain.so.

Anyone help me will be grateful

edit :

this is my proj architecture

[image]

Comment: Same problem for me started after I upgrade AndroidStudio to version 3.4 (and gragle to 5.1.1, ndk 19c, android gradle plugin 3.4) So I have to try revert to AndroidStudio 3.3.2, ndk19b, gradle 4.10.3)

Comment: On latest AndroidStudio Canary with latest gradle(5.4) plugin same problem

Comment: Finally,I use ndk-build intead,and it works well

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution on [android-ndk github issues](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/929), seems to there was problem with finding library for dynamic linking of **libdl.so** library, where **dlopen** function is declared.

So you need to change:
`find_library(ANDROID_DL_LIBRARY dl)` to 
`find_library(ANDROID_DL_LIBRARY NAMES libdl.so dl)` in *SDL2/CMakeLists.txt*

Comment: This works for me only for armeabi-v7a but form arm64-v8a - not. Try with NDK20b

Answer (score 2):

For now I found only one solution: downgrade NDK to r18b (r19c - not working). And `dlopen` start loading library. I can't find out what exactly happened course `dlerror` always return (null) no mater what I try to load shared library from other shared library. You can find old ndk release here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html dounload and extract then add in your local.properties file:

```
ndk.dir=/home/<your_path>/android-ndk-r18b
```

**Update:**
New NDK have stub for dlopen and other C-functions, previous NDK implement it directly, now you have to select minimal target to 21 or use old NDK